# Ruby error: undefined method `shift'

Tags: ruby

Brand new to Ruby. There are a couple of array methods I can't access.

EDIT:

I originally had:

```
puts 'give me a number to find phi of: '
K = gets
List = Array.new(K)  #{|i| i}
List.drop(2)
List puts
```

Rec'd the error: in `initialize': no implicit conversion of String into Integer

so I changed line 3 above to:

```
List = Array.new(K.to_i)  #{|i| i}
```

and am now receiving: undefined method `List' for main:Object

I'm trying to create an array based on user input, then drop or shift the first 2 elements of the array (the 0 and 1)

=================================
original post was unclear:

puts 'give me a number to find phi of: '
K = gets
puts K.shift

I'm sure it's something easy but can't figure it out. Am I missing a basic library or something? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what does `ruby --version` in the command line output?

Comment: C:\RubyAuto\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:/Users/ding/Primes/Primes
-e:1:in `load': C:/Users/ding/Primes/Primes:2: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
ruby -- version i
                 ^
 from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: What is it that you're trying to accomplish with this code? Why do you want to convert your input into an array?

Comment: I'm trying to find all primes betw 2 and K (where K is user input).  I'm using:   List = Array.new(K.to_i)  #{|i| i}    to convert K to an integer and create an array from 0 to K, then drop or shift the first 2 items in the array ( the 0 & 1).

Comment: See my answer on the easiest way to do that. You can use the prime library in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest way to find all primes between 2 and K in Ruby, you don't have to invent your own algo for finding primes when there's one already(http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html)

```
require 'prime'

def find_primes_between_2_and(a_number)
  Prime.each(a_number).map do |prime|
    prime
  end
end

puts 'Give me a number up to which to find primes:'
number = gets.to_i
puts find_primes_between_2_and(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running thru Chris Pike's Ruby "Learning to Program" & am doing it as an exercise. But hey, thanks for the help.

My problem on the shift was passing it w/o a parameter. It should have been List.shift(2)

Thanks much!